# Find the numbers in sequence

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Find the next 3 numbers in

> 1.1,  2.4,  3.9,  5.6,  7.5,  __,  __,  __

And specify the relation .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $f(x)=x+\frac{x^2}{10}$

The next 3 numbers are

> $9.6, 11.9, 14.4$.